# Custom Controller - Stay on page after save

Tags: visualforce

After the user clicks save I don't want them redirected to another page. I want them to stay on the same page so they can keep entering items. My issue is the sidebar and header keep reappearing. A refresh gets rid of them but I don't want this page in page effect.

I have the following VF page:

```
<apex:page Controller="Admin_Tracking_Controller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <style>
        //removed for post
    </style>

    <apex:form style="background-color:#D8DDE7;height:350px" >
        <div class="h1">
            Admin Time Tracking
        </div>
        <div class="b1">       
            <apex:outputText >Activity:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Activity__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Account:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Account__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >The Hub:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.The_Hub__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Carrier:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Carrier__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Time Utilized:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Time_Utilized__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Notes:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Tracking_Notes__c}" style="resize:none;height:50px;"/>
        </div> 

        <div class="b2" align="center" draggable="false" > 
            <apex:commandLink value="Save Time" action="{!save}" target="_self" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" />
        </div> 

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

And my controller:

```
public class Admin_Tracking_Controller {

    public Admin_Tracking__c adminTracking { get; set; }

    public Admin_Tracking_Controller() {

    }

    public PageReference save() {
        //return new ApexPages.StandardController(adminTracking).save();
        insert adminTracking;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before save:

[image]

After save: (kinda picture in picture)

[image]

Comment: try removing target="_self" from <apex:commandLink/>

Comment: I added that to try and get it to stop moving away.

Comment: Added that as an answer so others might get benefited

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try removing `target="_self"` from `<apex:commandLink/>` which is driving this navigation.